# JS string add to end of all links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript string called popupContent.

popupContent contains an `<li><a>blabla</a><li><li><a>blabla</a><li><li><a>blabla</a><li>` and so on, and so on list. Ofc. with url's inside the a tags.

I want to add something at the end of all my a tags, to be exact i want to add the parameter called "link".

Can anyone help me out with this? how do i add something at the end of all links?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I used a `tempdiv` for the demo. At first I set the `popContent` as its `html()` then. By iterating all `<a>` in tempdiv, their `href` and `html` has been set to new link i.e `www.newlink.com`

```js
popContent='<ul>'+
                '<li><a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a></li>'+
                '<li><a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a></li>'+
            '</ul>';
            
$(function(){  
  $('#tmpdiv').html(popContent); //
  $('#tmpdiv a').each(function(){
    $(this).href="http://www.newlink.com";
    $(this).html("www.newlink.com");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tmpdiv"></div>
```

Comment: But my problem is that my a tag could be like:
`<a href="http://google.dk/one">` but it could also be like `<a href="http://google.dk/two">` but to each of them i want them to look like `<a href="http://google.dk/one/AddSomething">` and `<a href="http://google.dk/two/AddSomething">`

Comment: without the closing tag `</a>`?

Comment: A tags already are closed and still has to be. The thing i want to change is just adding something at the end of all the href's inside my string. The value i want to add is the same for all href's so for example `<a href="http://google.dk/one">` would change to `<a href="http://google.dk/one/Value">`

Comment: Then you can set `popupContent` as html of an element using jQuery and then you can easily control it.

Comment: It comes in a popup, so i have to replace the links inside my javascript string, with javascript before calling the popup call.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/0q5zpxep/)

```
<ul>
<li><a>blabla</a></li>
<li><a>blabla</a></li>
<li><a>blabla</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
$.each($('a'),function(i,data){
$(data).html($(data).html()+' link')
})

})
```

And please use jquery library

Comment: Im sorry. This doesnt really fit my needs, i think i simplified the question too much. I want to add something at the end of all my href's in my string, so i can output my string in popup with all the changed links. so a link to google.com could in this case change to google.com/Value, but the link could also be google.de and then i want to add the same /Value at the end. Is this possible?